# C++ parsing as custom language Interpreter

Tags: c++, string, file, parsing, input

I need to parse input text file as custom language that i should interpret it's commands (line by line) and execute it, that's the input i should expect:

```
#Some variables
myInt = 2
myFloat = 2.5
myString = “Hello”

#Lists
myList = (myInt, myFloat, myInt + myFloat)
myOtherList = (myFloat + myFloat, myInt+ myInt)
subList = myList[:1]
completeList = myList + myOtherList + subList

#This should have no effect (it is ok if it is being calculated)
2+4

#Now some printing
print(myString)
print(“World”)
print(completeList)
print(completeList[3])

#Some syntax errors
b = “hello, this string is not enclosed right
c = myString + completeList
d = myInt + SOME_VARIABLE_I_HAVENT_DEFINED_YET

#First string to appear makes everything a string
print(1 + 2 + 15.5 + 2.2 + “Hi” + 3 + 4 + 6)
print(1 + 2 + 15.5 + 2.2 + 3 + 4 + 6 + “hi”)
print((1,2))
```

So I already have a first checking function, now I know when it's print/assign/comment/bad syntax command or whatever. I now should parse what inside the print function and the assign commands, I should ignore white spaces, they also might not be as delimiters to count on.

Please guide me a bit, what string functions i should use and how in order to to make it work, I mean how you can cut to tokens and also identify the mathematical signs? I'm guessing it should use some stack to follow the parentheses of the list type and quotation signs, no? Any general and more detailed information will be appreciated, thanks(:

p.s.

That's the output for this code:

```
Hello
World
(2, 2.5, 4.5, 5.0, 4, 2, 2.5)
5.0
InvalidSyntax : b = “hello, this string is not enclosed right
InvalidSyntax : c = myString + completeList
UndefinedVariableName : SOME_VARIABLE_I_HAVENT_DEFINED_YET
20.7Hi346
33.7hi
(1,2)
```

I already have all the overloading operators for what I need, I only need to parse it right and send it to my already built functions.

Comment: Would it have been too much bother for you to capitalise your sentences?

Comment: Yes, someone who is inventing a grammar should use proper capitalization. Also, note that you have pasted curly quotes `“` and `”` into your example; this is probably not the intent for a programming language. Also, the examples make it look like a general purpose language with a kitchen sink of features. Start simple, for example just do arithmetic expressions first, then add named variables with simple assignment… Without scoping the problem the language should solve, this is Not a Real Question.

Comment: I capitalized my sentences, about the quotes thing, that's what I should expect for string type.

Comment: How in depth do you want to go ? An interpreter would just read and execute (which seems fine, as there is no function here), while you could also get more involved and create various steps of translations (tokens, AST, IR, executable).

Comment: It's an assignment about polymorphism, those INT,FLOAT,STRING and LIST types are my types that each contain the relevant real type, we use map to store those vars and we do those manipulation on them.

Answer (score 3):

A wonderful C++ library exists for that : [SPIRIT](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: I am not too sure about the wonderful (the compilation error are dreadful), but it sure is efficient.

Comment: Like a lot of boost sub libraries, the only think I can understand in a compilation error message, that is the line in my file where the error occurs :)

Comment: i cant use that, i should parse by my own, and it's also look too complicated for my needs, thanks.

Comment: @MatthieuM. What do you mean by saying "it sure is efficient"?  Have you compared it with other alternatives like [good old Bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/), [Lemon](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/lemon/) or [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/)?  How many times was it more efficient than its competitors in your benchmark result?

Comment: @nodakai: I'll let [ApochiQ speaks about this](http://code.google.com/p/scribblings-by-apoch/wiki/OptimizingBoostSpirit).

Comment: @MatthieuM. It was a fun reading, but the only thing I could read out of it was the fact that _by migration from `boost::spirit::classic` on which the Epoch compiler R11 was based to its successor `boost::spirit::qi`, a single parse pass of the compiler got (10 sec / 4 sec ==) 2.5 times faster._  It doesn't exclude a possible (though exaggerated) scenario where Bison could do the same job within 10 msec.

Comment: @nodakai: well, since he says (end of the article) that he is now under 9ms for the regular file, that would make both Spirit and Bison on par. I still don't understand what you're aiming at though, if you have figures, please do share them, if you don't... well parsing a 2MB file under 1s seems efficient to me.

Answer (score 1):

So you haven't had a chance to read [the Dragon Book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Book)...

How do you think about embedding Lua or Python interpreter into your product, instead of inventing your own language?  They are more common and full-fledged programming languages.  Moreover Google will help you find lots of tutorials on how to embed them, such as:

- http://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-embed-lua/

The disadvantage of inventing your own language is that: even after you successfully parsed your own language, you need to define **semantics** for it.  Parsing only deals  with the **syntax**, which is a different thing from the semantics.  I don't know your situation but both of them usually require too long time to learn for just a single software project.

As for Boost Spirit: I don't recommend to use it which was written by people who just wanted to show their smartness by writing it (but in the end showed their ignorance about what is practical software design.)